# 2 key presses in a row on Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a menu page that has a series of 2 digit shortcuts.. so I need to be able to listen for 2 key presses and then do something based on which two keys were pressed.

I have managed to get this working for one key:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F) {
            Log.d("Test", "YOU PRESSED THE F KEY");
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```

But I am still trying to figure out how I would add in listening for the second key press and then starting the activity. Thank you

Comment: remember the last key code and do the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the 2 keys are E and F. Change your code as below .

```
  private int keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN;

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E  && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F) {
            Log.d("Test", "YOU PRESSED THE E KEY and then F kEY");
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        }else {
            keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
};
```